# Universal application with IOS 4.2 and Xcode 3.2

Tags: xcode, ios, universal-binary

I'm developping Iphone application and I want to convert it to a universal one. 
I found many tutorial that deals with this issue but they seems to be ancohérent to the new release of SDK and Xcode.
As many said I think that making a universal application is so easy.
Can you give me the necessery steps or a tutorial link? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you will find necessary information and steps in this tutorial

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/04/converting-iphone-apps-to-universal.html

and as a side note you should be aware of converting an existing app to universal app

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/4/7/converting-to-a-universal-app-part-i.html

Comment: Thanks Famous Guy. I'll follow the tutos, and I hope I'll get good result.

Comment: @Famous Guy : I had the perception that a universal application is application that can be run in Intel based Mac and PPC based Mac. But what it's got to do if we develop an iPhone app? Thanks

Comment: @swdev. A universal app is one that runs in iPhone, iPad, iTouch, essentially all the iOS devices as far as I know. I don't think it translates to Mac OSX development. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Thanks for that info. But, my perception is Universal application is the one that run on Mac Intel and Mac PPC. Btw, I haven't succeed on doing the conversion either... so sad

Comment: @Yko using this link, http://lowendmac.com/misc/11mr/mb-rosetta.html, I think the correct understanding of Universal application is indeed it can run on Intel Based mac and PPC. I quote, "If you run Word for Mac 2008, which is Universal Binary and was only superseded in 2010, you won't be able to install it on Lion. Why? Because Word 2008 uses PPC code in its installer. So you'll have to buy another version of Word."

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the link swdev but the OP is asking in regards to iPhone development which is iOS apps. In iOS apps, I think universal refers to both iPad and iPhone.